# Filtering based on the first insurance ID

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list of patients from my insurance company, for some reason sometimes they are given a new policy number, but it should not, it's the oldest insurance number the one that matters, here is an example.

```
InsuranceNumber <- c("00932", "00932", "00932", "00987", "00987", "00915", "00915", "00923" , "00977")
PatientName <- c("Patient1", "Patient1", "Patient1", "Patient1", "Patient1", "Patient1", "Patient1", "Patient2", "Patient2")

df <- data.frame(InsuranceNumber, PatientName)

df

InsuranceNumber            PatientName
00932                      Patient1 
00932                      Patient1 
00932                      Patient1  
00987                      Patient1
00987                      Patient1
00915                      Patient1
00915                      Patient1
00923                      Patient2
00977                      Patient2
```

I need a code in R that returns a data frame that, only takes the first Insurance number and removes all others, it should be like this

```
   "InsuranceNumber"          "PatientName"
    00932                      Patient1 
    00932                      Patient1 
    00932                      Patient1
    00923                      Patient2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(PatientName) %>% 
  filter(InsuranceNumber == first(InsuranceNumber))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   PatientName [2]
  InsuranceNumber PatientName
  <chr>           <chr>      
1 00932           Patient1   
2 00932           Patient1   
3 00932           Patient1   
4 00923           Patient2
```

Comment: I edited the problem

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, in this case, what does %>% mean?

Comment: I recommend this post: https://style.tidyverse.org/pipes.html

Answer (score 0):

We can use `subset`  from `base R`with `%in%` (or `==`) ones that are not `duplicated`

```
subset(df, InsuranceNumber %in% InsuranceNumber[!duplicated(PatientName)])
  InsuranceNumber PatientName
1           00932    Patient1
2           00932    Patient1
3           00932    Patient1
8           00923    Patient2
```

NOTE: we are not using any group by approach and should be faster

Comment: That will work if there is only one name, but its a long list with many names and everytime it happens i need to get only the first one since its already sorted

Comment: @RandomPerson please check the updated solution

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `ave` -

```
result <- subset(df, InsuranceNumber == ave(InsuranceNumber, PatientName, 
                      FUN = function(x) x[1]))

result

#   InsuranceNumber PatientName
#1           00932    Patient1
#2           00932    Patient1
#3           00932    Patient1
#8           00923    Patient2
```